# Load levels randomly after level 50 has been played and won. The random levels will be from level 1 to 50 and they won't repeat twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 50 levels, these levels are prefabs (not scenes) and are being loaded by the help of script. What I want is that when I have played 50 levels. It should start randomizing levels from those 50 levels I have played earlier. Currently I have used a list for this purpose which stores integers from 0 to 49 since my levels identify as 0 to 49 for level to level 50 respectively. It worked for once like it loaded a random level once and then for example if the random level was 30 it would start loading levels from 30 onwards, i.e. 31, 32, 32 and so on. Currently, I get an error of transform child out of bounds when I win level 50 and click next button.

Here is the logic: Here I am making a bool variable set to true when I start level 50.

```
 if (EnvirenmentNo == 49)
    {
        lastLevel = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("startRandom",startRandom?1:0);
        startRandom = true;
        //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentLevel", EnvirenmentNo);
       
    }
```

This is the logic for loading next level. The else part of the code loads the next levels normally, the if part  is where I want the level to be loaded randomly from my played levels till they are all played. For this I am using a list and removing the random number before starting the level. Nothing seems to work rn.

```
else if (btn == "next")
    {

        if (lastLevel)
        {
            int nextLevelIndex = Random.Range(0,randomLevels.Count);
            int nextLevel = randomLevels[nextLevelIndex];
            EnvirenmentNo = nextLevel;
            randomLevels.Remove(nextLevelIndex);
            lastLevel = true;
            startRandom = true;
            EnvirenmentNo = Random.Range(0, 50);
            //currentLevel++;
            LoadingPanel.SetActive(true);
            Finish.Instance.collider2D.enabled = false;
            LevelCompletePanel.SetActive(false);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("restart", 1);
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            //VehicleSimpleControl._instance.rigidBody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
        }
        else
        {
            
            //DrawingManager.Instance.posCount = 0;
            EnvirenmentNo ++;
            //currentLevel++currentLevel++;
            LoadingPanel.SetActive(true);
            Finish.Instance.collider2D.enabled = false;
            LevelCompletePanel.SetActive(false);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("restart", 1);
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            //VehicleSimpleControl._instance.rigidBody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
        }
```

This is the list and integer I have created,

```
protected const int MAX = 50;

public static List<int> randomLevels = new List<int>();
```

Earlier I was not able to randomize the levels. Now the levels are being randomized once the user finishes level 50. But there is still one problem, the levels are repeating. I am removing the index of the level randomized but still after few levels it somehow occurs again. Like currently I had level 49 come 3 times, level 18 and 25 2times. I have also added the list and the integer I am using in list in my question. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is clearly in `c#`. Your question also doesn't really directly focus on any specific topic about object-oriented-programming and its patterns so [`[oop]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oop/info) doesn't really apply to your question either.

Comment: @derHugo sir, I'll keep this in mind next time. Thankyou for noticing the problems with question and tag sir.

Comment: @derHugo Sir, can you kindly look into the issue here? My levels are being randomized after level 50 but they are also repeating. All I want is that these levels must appear only once and when all levels have been played it should move me to the main menu or stop loading more levels. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all I can tell from the little code you provide is that you completely ignore the

```
EnvirenmentNo = nextLevel;
```

and overwrite it again using a hard coded

```
EnvirenmentNo = Random.Range(0, 50);
```

just a few lines later, which doesn't prevent any duplicate levels.

---

Beyond that it is really hard to tell since as said we don't know your full code but most probably you should also somewhere store which levels have already been played so you don't repeat the random ones later.

You could e.g. save and load them using

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("randomLevels", string.Join(",", randomLevels.ToArray()));
```

and

```
using System.Linq;

...

randomLevels.Clear();
randomLevels.AddRange(PlayerPrefs.GetString("randomLevels").Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)));
```

---

Also note

> Here I am making a bool variable set to true when I start level 50.

this is logically wrong. You would want to do this **after finishing** level 50 only, not when you start it!

Comment: sir sorry to bother you again, when I am using PlayerPrefs.SetString("randomLevels", string.Join(','), randomLevels);
it gives an error: Cannot resolve method ' Join(char)', candidates are: string Join(string, params object[]) (in class string) string Joing(string, params string[]) (in class string)

Comment: It should be `string.Join(",", randomLevels.ToArray())` - double quotes around the comma to make that a string, and no `)`

Answer (score 0):

You should change `startRandom` to `true` before `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` to save the right value.

Comment: Actually, I have fixed the random level generation issue I have another issue. Let me update the question.

Comment: Sir, I have edited the question with changes. You can have a look at it. Thanks in Advance!